# Combine 2 Dataframes when rows are not matching and put columns side by side for comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have these dataframes in hand and I would like to combine them into one dataframe but only if they have any unmatching rows and for comparison sake, I would like to put the columns for the dataframes next to each other.

```
initial = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['123', '456', '789', '000'],
                     'Day': ['Mon','Tues','Wed','Thurs'],
                     'Value': ['5', '10', '11', '12'],
                      'Letter': ['Z', 'X', 'C', 'V']}) 

updated = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['456', '123', '000', '789'],
                      'Day': ['Tues','Mon','Thurs','Wed'],
                       'Value': ['10', '8', '12', '13'],
                      'Letter': ['X', 'Z', 'C', 'V']})
```

After merging them, I would like them to look like this. (Note: the 'Value' columns in both initial and updated are side by side , similarly for 'Letter' column as well.

| ID | Day | Value_initial | Value_updated | Letter_initial | Letter_updated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Mon | 5 | 8 | Z | Z |
| 789 | Wed | 11 | 13 | C | C |
| 000 | Thurs | 12 | 12 | V | C |

Does anyone have any idea on how I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sample data you provided, even `ID`: `000` has unmatched data in `Letter` column.

**Try code:**

```
df = pd.merge(initial,updated,on='ID', how='inner',suffixes=('_initial', '_updated'))
df = df[(df['Day_initial'] != df['Day_updated']) | (df['Value_initial'] != df['Value_updated']) | (df['Letter_initial'] != df['Letter_updated'])]
df = df.rename(columns={'Day_initial': 'Day'}).drop('Day_updated',axis=1)
df
```

Prints:

```
    ID    Day Value_initial Letter_initial Value_updated Letter_updated
0  123    Mon             5              Z             8              Z
2  789    Wed            11              C            13              V
3  000  Thurs            12              V            12              C
```

**Alternative (As per comments)** : If there are too many columns to compare, then the below approach is to delete the common row from the two dfs first and then do a merge. The code assumes are all IDs present in `initial` is present in `updated` as well.

```
df1 = initial.sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = updated.sort_values('ID').reset_index(drop=True)
df3_common = df1[df1.isin(df2)].dropna()
df1 = df1[~df1.isin(df3_common)].dropna()
df2 = df2[~df2.isin(df3_common)].dropna()
df = pd.merge(df1,updated,on='ID', how='inner',suffixes=('_initial', '_updated'))
df = df.rename(columns={'Day_initial': 'Day'}).drop('Day_updated',axis=1)
df = df[['ID','Day','Value_initial','Value_updated','Letter_initial','Letter_updated']]
df
```

Prints:

```
    ID    Day Value_initial Value_updated Letter_initial Letter_updated
0  000  Thurs            12            12              V              C
1  123    Mon             5             8              Z              Z
2  789    Wed            11            13              C              V
```

Comment: Oh right. I realised that. I've edited it. Is there no way to re-arrange the columns?

Comment: In addition, I would like to add this would be great for a few columns but assuming we have 100 columns, checking if each column is not equal to another would seemed rough.

Comment: just `df = df[['ID','Day','Value_initial','Value_updated','Letter_initial','Letter_updated']]`

Comment: I have added a code which will eliminate the need for checking if you have many columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could `append` instead of merge and `drop_duplicates()`. Then, `pivot` the dataframe. This will also order as desired:

```
df = (initial.assign(col='initial')                            # create new col for each dataframe as we merge, so we can use as the column for the pivot later 
      .append(updated.assign(col='updated'))                   # append row-wise so we can use drop_duplicates
      .drop_duplicates(initial.columns, keep=False))           # keep=False drops both rows that are duplicated
      .pivot(index=['ID', 'Day'], columns='col').reset_index() # we transform dataframe from long-to-wide with pivot
df.columns = [f'{col[0]}_{col[1]}' for col in df.columns]      # fix the names of the columns so they are as desired and not multi-level
df
Out[1]: 
   ID_   Day_ Value_initial Value_updated Letter_initial Letter_updated
0  000  Thurs            12            12              V              C
1  123    Mon             5             8              Z              Z
2  789    Wed            11            13              C              V
```